# MongoDB - Select all documents by the count of an array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my current project I have a structure like this:

```
"squad": {
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "empty": true
        },
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "empty": true
        },
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "empty": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to query every squad with mongodb which have at least, lets say 3 empty member slots. I've googled and only found aggregate and $size, which seem to only select an array count not something per field.
Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query :

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$squad.members"},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id",count:{$sum:{$cond: [{$eq: ['$squad.members.empty', true]}, 1, 0]}}}},
  {$match: {count: {$gte: 3}}}
])
```

In this query applied *conditional sum* and then check the count is *greater than or equal  3*

Answer (score 0):

It will return all documents will empty slots greater than 3

```
db.squad.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$squad.members"},
  {$match:{"squad.members.empty": true}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id",count:{$sum:1}}},
  {$match: {count: {$gt: 3}}}
])
```